# How to get eslint in Visual Studio Code to allow double quotes?

Tags: vue.js, visual-studio-code, eslint

- I created a vue-js CLI project
- I want to be able to use double-quotes instead of single quotes
- when I use double quotes, `npm run dev` reports eslint errors
- **Where do I tell eslint to allow double quotes?**

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Check your `.eslintrc.js` file, you can either set the value of the `quotes` rule to `double` or set the error level to `warning` or disable it altogether. Have a look at the [docs](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/quotes). This would be an example:

```
"rules": {
    "quotes": ["error", "double"]
}
```

Comment: When I set it to `quotes: ["error", "double"]` then it gets errors on the single quotes. How do I disable this checking all together so I can use single or double quotes? The syntax to disable is not apparent on the docs page.

Comment: I'm looking for something like this `quotes: ["ignore", "double"],`

Comment: It says `If you do not need consistency in your string styles, you can safely disable this rule.` but it doesn't say how.

Answer (score 5):

`quotes: [0, "double"]` works for me

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes it is cumbersome to find a specific syntax to disallow a specific eslint rule. In this situations you can use "global" disabling for a code block as the following:

```
/*eslint-disable */

//suppress all warnings between comments
console.info("foo");

/*eslint-enable */
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use the ESLint extension https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dbaeumer.vscode-eslint.

It comes with a command to initialize the .eslintrc file :

Run
`Ctrl+Maj+P`
then
`ESLint : Create ESLint configuration`

In the resulting .eslintrc.js file that has been generated at the root of your Workspace add the `quotes: [0, "double"]` line as stated by others.

File should look something like this

```
module.exports = {
  quotes: [0, "double"]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way which is the easier one is to just go into the.eslintignore file and add * at the end of the file will do the magic for you

Answer (score 0):

The following rule will get rid of the double quotes error however then you will start getting single quotes error:

```
"rules": {
   "quotes": ["error", "double"]
}
```

And if you want to disable the quotes rule then add this:

```
rules: {
    quotes: "off"  
}
```